# Ansible: restart networking on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-12.04, ansible

If you need to restart the networking in the middle of a play on an Ubuntu server (12.04 in my case) you can't use `service`:

```
# service networking restart 
stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking
```

The following works on the command line, but with Ansible (1.8.4) it locks you out:

```
command: ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0
```

`ifdown` takes down the interface, but `ifup` doesn't run

How to restart the interface?

Comment: Why that? To me it appears to be perfectly on topic.

Comment: What's with the down votes and no comments to suggest why?

Comment: there was some comment, complaining it would have been off topic. The comment was deleted, not the down-votes though...

Comment: thanks, just wondering what I can do better :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to run the command in a new shell:

```
command: bash -c "ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0"
```

You can also use the shell module:

```
shell: "ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0"
```

Comment: why can't you use `shell`?

Comment: You can, but it is recommended to use `command` instead of `shell` [unless shell is explicitly required](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html#notes). I have updated my answer with the shell module version for reference.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to wait 1 sec between ifdown and ifup and run ifup independent of exit code from ifdown. Also you probably not want run reset network everytime you run this ansible playbook, so a when condition will prevent this:

```
- name: Restart all network interfaces except loopback device
  shell: "ifdown --exclude=lo -a; sleep 1; ifup --exclude=lo -a"
  when: configure_lxc_bridge|changed
```